# Find duplicates in a string array in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicates in an array and put only the duplicates in an array.
The code im using is the following

```
    Dim duplicates As List(Of String) =
               WithDuplicates.GroupBy(Function(n) n) _
               .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1) _
               .Select(Function(g) g.First) _
               .ToList()
    Dim DuplicatesOnly As String() = duplicates.ToArray
```

WithDuplicates is the Array that contains the duplicates. Before, I used a richtextbox instead of a array but I had to switch to an array because of threading. I don't know why my code isnt working anymore. Any ideas how I could get this working?

**Edit**: The code above does indeed work, another part of my code caused the error.

Comment: What is not working? Note that it's a case-sensitive comparison; what if you add `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` (or `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`) to the grouping?

Comment: @Jimi Unfortunately I dont even know what isn't working. Where would I put your code?

Comment: How could you possibly not know what is wrong with that code? You said *my code isn't working anymore*, so how did it work before? Is the content of `DuplicatesOnly` that is different from what you expected? Something else? -- What has *Threading* to do with this?

Comment: @jimi haha right, my thought exactly. Moving from a control to a List might have something to do with a UI cross thread issue

Comment: @Jimi DuplicatesOnly is just empty. Also, trying to show the content of it line to line in a messagebox (with a foreach statement) doesn't do anything, it doesn't show an messagebox neither does it show an error.

Comment: Well, then `DuplicatesOnly` is empty because no duplicates were found or `WithDuplicates`  is empty -- When you post your code, you always need to give it context. You also need to debug your code: put a breakpoint in the first line, inspect the variables / values and step in one line at the time. Get rid of any MessageBox, print to the Output Window, when needed, instead (`Console.WriteLine()` or `Debug.WriteLine()`) -- What is the content of `WithDuplicates` and where does it come from? How is threading involved? Update your questions with this information.

Comment: @Jimi very sorry for wasting your time here. The problem was actually another part of the code which I changed for debugging, but that caused it to not detect any duplicates at all. Again, thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You just need to select the key instead of the first.

```vb
Dim withDuplicates As New List(Of String) From {"a", "b", "c", "a", "c"}

Dim duplicates As List(Of String) =
    withDuplicates.GroupBy(Function(n) n).
    Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).
    Select(Function(g) g.Key).ToList()
Dim DuplicatesOnly As String() = duplicates.ToArray

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", DuplicatesOnly))
```

> a, c

Comment: @Jimi yeah I guess, haven't had my coffee yet... Maybe I should have waited until I heard "what" isn't working

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
Dim duplicates As List(Of String) = WithDuplicates.Distinct.Where(Function(el) Array.IndexOf(WithDuplicates, el) <> Array.LastIndexOf(WithDuplicates, el)).ToList
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if there **are** duplicates.  Jimi's first comment may be pertinent, but your question lacks that detail.

```
    Dim WithDuplicates As New List(Of String) From {"aa", "b", "c", "aa", "c", "AA", "c"}
    ' Dim WithDuplicates As New List(Of String) From {"aa", "b", "c"} ', "aa", "c", "AA", "c"}

    Dim duplicates() As String
    duplicates = WithDuplicates.GroupBy(Function(n) n).
                    Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).
                    Select(Function(g) g.First).ToArray
```